# How to save a YOLOv8 custom trained model and load it in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, yolov8

I have trained a yolov8 model on Colab. The model is saved as `best.pt` and `last.pt` in `/content/runs/detect/train2/weights`

I want to apply the model to a live webcam video with jupyter notebook. (since colab does not support local webcam).

I downloaded both `best.pt` and `last.pt` files and added them to a file in the jupyter environment but when trying to load that model OSError occurs.

`OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:`

```
import os

cd D:\ML

from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO('D:\\ML\runsColab\RunsDetectTrain2\best.pt')
```

This is my code to load the saved model.
[Here's the actual location of these two files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Iyyo.png)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried model = YOLO(os.path.abspath('D:\ML\runsColab\RunsDetectTrain2\best.pt')? Note the removal of the double \ after D:

Comment: I changed the path as `D:\\ML\\runsColab\\RunsDetectTrain2\\best.pt` and it worked. Figured paths in JUpyter should be mentioned with double slashes.